# Is the DPLL algorithm complexity in terms of # of clauses or # of variables?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I'm a bit confused how worst case complexity is estimated for the [DPLL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm). Is it in terms of number of clauses, number of variables, or something else?

Comment: It could also be in terms of the input length. Do you have any specific analysis in mind? Usually they explain what their variables mean.

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) Worst case complexity says it's O(e^n).

Comment: Here $n$ is probably input length. But don't trust Wikipedia - find an actual source. I see that Wikipedia doesn't quote any, so there's no reason to believe it. In particular, I suspect that by $O(e^n)$, they really mean $O(c^n)$ for some constant $c > 1$.

Comment: Input length being the number of clauses? Or the number of vairables. The DPLL is used to solve [k-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), which is known to be NP-complete. However, I don't understand if it is NP-complete based on the number of variables or the number of clauses.

Comment: Input length being the length of the input as a string. Roughly the total number of literals appearing in all the clauses.

Comment: The input length of the string wouldn't make sense in the context of k-SAT, because the input length of the string is the number of clauses * k, where k is a constant and would be dropped in the big O notation.

Comment: DPLL works for general SAT instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the papers I've read the time complexity of DPLL is expressed in terms of the number of variables in the CNF formula.  Using the number of clauses is inappropriate in general because it is known that random k-SAT instances go through an easy-hard-easy transition if you fix the number of variables and increase the number of clauses.  The solution space goes from underconstrained to overconstrained as the number of clauses increases with the hard instances clustering between those extremes.

Comment: Just to clarify what we mean by "number of variables": In a formula, we could have n variables, c clauses, and k literals per clause where a literal could be one of n unique variables with a truth value of True or False.